# Find Link in WatIn returns the same link every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

I am using WatIn and I have a list of url's. Every url opens a page and and on each page I have an element `a` (link). In the browser I see these links every time new href of link by my in code I get the same `href` all the time

My code

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DateTime> _link in fLinks)
{ 
   browser.GoTo("https://www.test.com/web/Processing?#");
   browser.WaitForComplete();
   string Link = "https://www.test.com/web/Processing?";
   string FileFullName = _link.Key;
   browser.GoToNoWait(Link);
   Thread.Sleep(3000);
   string LinkHtml = "";

   // here I see new link in browser window
   bool exist = browser.Link(Find.ByText("download")).Exists;
   if (exist) LinkHtml = browser.Link(Find.ByText("download")).OuterHtml;
   Link temlLink = browser.Link(Find.ByText("download"));

   // but here in LinkHtml I get the same (first href) all the time 
}
```

So does anyone see where the problem is? Why am I getting the same link every time?

Comment: No.this is file path i use it to safe file,it not full code, i just copied the  part with a problem.

Comment: Why do you want to navigate to 'https://www.test.com/web/Processing?#' and then again to particular link? Also, please post a 'Key', to see what it has.

If I understood you correctly, there is page and it has links. You need to navigate to that link (passed by for loop) and validate something. If it so, then instead of 

    browser.GoToNoWait(Link); use

    browser.Link(Find.ByText(link)).Click();

Comment: I can't use Click(); instead of  GoToNoWait(Link),because it never complite,i solved this problem with New page i just open new browers each time and all works fine.thx for the help.